# how to place textbox in dojo grid?

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a requirement where i need place textbox in the cell and enter the value and have to read the value on submitaction. I have tried writing the code like below...

```
     field : 'costCenter',
      name : "Cost Center",
     width : '180px',
    height : '20px',
    styles : "text-align: center;",
cellStyles : "text-align: left;font-weight: normal;",
   classes : 'grid_header_title',
  editable : true,
      type : dojox.grid.cells.DateTextBox,
        formatter: function(item){
            var txt= new dijit.form.TextBox();
        return txt;
```

this doesn't work for me. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

This will palce a textbox in your datagrid

```
    var _count = 0;
{
    field      : 'costCenter',
    name       : "Cost Center",
    style      : "width: 180px; height: 20px; text-align: center;",
    editable   : true,
    type       : dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
    formatter  : function(){
       return new dijit.form.TextBox({
         id: "id_"+_count++
       });
    }
}
```